# Need help implementing a class into another block of code and running a class java

Tags: java, file, class

Ok so I am working on this project that requires a file to be loaded. My teacher has written this code for us to use to load the file. I am trying to figure out now how to take this class and use it in another block of code. I have browsed around the internet but I am still quite confused. And a direct example would be great.
The other question I have is how can I run this class. When my teacher runs classes and other files like this they run without a problem but when I try to run them despite using the same code it won't allow me to run it.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AltFileLoader {

    private String path;

    public AltFileLoader(String file_path) {

        path = file_path;

    }

    public ArrayList<String> loadFile() throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(path));
        ArrayList<String> allTheLines = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (inFile.hasNext()) {

            allTheLines.add(inFile.next());

        }

        inFile.close();
        return allTheLines;
    }

}
```

And for the start of my hangman code I have

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Random;

class Hangman extends AltFileLoader {
    public String allTheLines;
         String getallTheLines() {
          return(allTheLines);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
  System.out.println("If this prints then it works!");
  }
}
```

So basically I am stuck trying to implement this class file. And then I am going to work from there. Not being able to pull in a text document has really stopped me up on this.

And when I try to run the class I am getting the error

Error: Main method not found in class AltFileLoader, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

constructor AltFileLoader in class AltFileLoader cannot be applied to given types;
class Hangman extends AltFileLoader {
^

And this above is the error I get when trying to implement the class into the hangman code.

Comment: Can you post your main? what have you in therE?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking?

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is

Comment: @Nafarious Where did you implements this class?? have you tried to use this class??

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to implement this class into another project. And also wondering why it won't run for me.

Comment: `And also wondering why it won't run for me` it will not run for you because there is no [`main` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html#MAIN) which is entry point of most Java applications. Also to use method from this class you need to create instance of this class and invoke method on that instance. It looks like you should start from basics before you go deeper in Java. Consider reading [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), or at least some of its [first chapters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html).

Comment: I understood that it wouldn't run without a main a method, I was just trying to figure out why my professor was able to run it. So I am trying to see what I am missing.

Comment: In the same vein of that Hangman class I keep getting the **error** Hangman.java:17: error: ';' expected
      String getallTheLines() {

Comment: @Nafarious: your error doesn't matter for your assignment because you are going to have to scrap your Hangman code anyway and start afresh. Again, do not have it extend AltFileLoader, again, give it an AltFileLoader instance and call its method when needed.

Answer (score 1):

To use this class, you would create an instance of it, passing in a String that represents a file path to the file of interest. then when you want your ArrayList of Strings, call the loadFile() method off of your AltFileLoader instance. Note that you'll have to somehow handle the FileNotFoundException by either catching it (as shown below) or by letting the method that this code is in declare the method as throwing this exception (like your instructor does in his code of the method):

```
AltFileLoader altFileLoader = new AltFileLoader(filePath);
ArrayList<String> stringList = null;
try {
   stringList = altFileLoader.loadFile();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

**Edit**
As for this question:

> And also wondering why it won't run for me.

We unfortunately have no idea. You'll have to show us how you've tried to use it, and any errors you might be getting.

---

**Edit 2**

I see another major problem. Your Hangman class is extending the AltFileLoader and it shouldn't be doing this. You should instead have your code ***use*** an instance of the AltFileLoader rather than extend. This is inappropriate use of inheritance because Hangman does not intrinsically pass the **is-a** test for AltFileLoader -- it isn't a specialized type of AltFileLoader.

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was missing something! Sorry a bit out of it today. I added the error code and my small snippet of code for the class I am trying to implement it into.

Comment: @Nafarious: that snippet of code does nothing of the kind. You don't show where you ever create or use a AltFileLoader instance. Also, you need to give a main method to whatever class will be starting your program, and you need to use Java to start the main class.

Comment: What do you mean? Yea I was just messing around with things on that class but I figured I could add it. So if I implement the code you just gave me into that. What exactly would it look like?

Comment: @Nafarious: you're using inheritance incorrectly. You probably were never told to have Hangman ***extend*** AltFileLoader, and that's because it shouldn't and it's messing you up royally. Get rid of that. See edit to my answer for more, but this is a major problem with your code.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Thank you for that. I wasn't quite sure how I needed to pass that class in. But that makes sense.